# AMF call vs Javascript call to facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, amfphp

I have a flash application which would be on Facebook . I was wondering currently I have two options in front of me either make javascript calls which will make AJAX calls and return the data to flash or make direct AMFPHP calls and get data into flash.

Which would be more faster? more importantly a better approach?

Answer (score 1):

amfphp is very compact and will likely be faster "in transit" than ajax calls, it'll also save you the round trip to javascript.

What is the better choice really depends on what you're more comfortable with.